# How to reverse a stack without using extra space… fp-style

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, stack

I'm attempting to dive deeper into FP, a little further down the surface of map-reduce stuff I've been doing for the most part lately — yes, I know there's much more, hence...

Anyway, a classic problem in imperative programming is stack reversal "without using extra space". The solution is typically using the call stack in double recursion, to get to the bottom of the stack, take the bottom element, and bring it back up to the outer recursion which re-builds the stack in reverse order. I've been trying to solve the same problem in Haskell, but I can't quite figure out how to express it in that language. Hints?

**EDIT** Yes, using the stack **is** using extra space, the question is a trick one often used in exams and interviews to see how people think about stuff. Also, yes, I know stuff is immutable, so creating a duplicate stack that is the reverse of the one given is obviously acceptable.

(btw, y'all have failed the interview…, jk)

Comment: Note that using the call stack isn't really "without using extra space"...

Comment: What is "extra space"?  Lists in Haskell are immutable.  If you reverse one, you have to create a new one.  Unless you write the super-naive O(n^2) reverse, you're already in good shape. The standard O(n) solution already minimizes allocations.

Comment: You cannot reverse a stack in O(1) space FP-style. In FP things are immutable. Your imperative solution uses O(n) space too because recursion requires space.

Comment: OK, the "no extra space" makes it a trick question, that's why it's often an exam/interview question. Can we get past that now?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `reverse = foldl (flip (:)) []`...

Comment: Remove all mention of "no extra space" from the question. What's left? How to reverse a stack?

Comment: @n.m. yes, but using double recursion, like you'd do in the imperative case.

Comment: @Morpheu5 Since there are no imperative loops in haskell, you'd use recursion anyway. Just try it.

Comment: @Bergi I'm well aware of that, my question was more like "how do I express this (doubly-)recursive algorithm in Haskell to reverse a stack – aka a list that can't be built back to front?" rather than "how do I do imperative loops in Haskell?"

Comment: @Morpheu5: The hard part in Haskell is to get an under-the-hood stack implementation that you can only `push` to/`pop` from. See [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#state) for an example how it could be done by representing it in the `State` monad. Then you can just use the same "double recursion" solution as presented elsewhere.

Comment: @Bergi please, no. A list in Haskell is a stack. There's no need to ever touch the State monad in this discussion.

Comment: @n.m.: Yeah, the answer to "*a classic problem in imperative programming is stack reversal  […]. I've been trying to solve the same problem in Haskell*" should be "in Haskell there is no problem". You could use the state monad to make it a problem though :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only efficient way to reverse a list is

```
reverse = revApp []

revApp acc [] = acc
revApp acc (x:xs) = revApp (x:acc) xs
```

There are various ways to express this idea, but they all lead to basically the same code. The idea is to deconstruct the list from front to back (in stack language, from top to bottom) and builds the new one from back to front.

---

There is no way to work entirely from front to back, because you don't know what the first element of the reversed list will be until you've seen the last element of the argument list. If you want, you *can* build the structure of the result list from front to back. This will be somewhat slower.

```
lazyReverse xs = zipWith' (flip const) xs (reverse xs)

zipWith' _ [] _ = []
zipWith' f (x:xs) ~(y:ys) = f x y : zipWith' f xs ys
```

The idea is to form the structure of the result list by copying the structure of the argument list (front to back) but to get its values from a reversed copy. I don't think there's any way to avoid the heap allocation this involves; the thunk intermediately representing each tail captures references to things that must, therefore, be on the heap and not the stack.

Comment: So, what if you imposed the extra constraint of not being able to build the list back to front – which is what happens in a stack?

Comment: @Morpheu5 There is only one way to build a list in Haskell: by prepending an element to a smaller list. "Back to front" refers to the order of elements in the original list.

Comment: @Morpheu5 Look again. The code posted in this answer takes a stack, and while it is non-empty, it recursively pops an element off the top of the stack (the `(x:xs)` bit), and pushes it onto a new stack (the `(x:acc)` bit). It uses precisely the same methods exposed by any stack ADT.

Comment: @Morpheu5, see the update. I don't think this is going to go anywhere useful, though.